# Having a problem with external .js file and using google loader?

Tags: jquery, html, external, local-storage

This code works PERFECTLY fine when I include the jQuery within the html document; however, it stops working completely if I put it into an external javascript file. I referenced the jQuery library before referencing the external js file, so I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm a beginner with jQuery already.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML 5 Stuff</title>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/html5.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<figure>
    <img src="http://www.yalibnan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/steve-jobs1.jpg" alt="Steve Jobs" />
    <figcaption>
        <p>Steve Jobs before giving up his title as CEO of Apple Inc.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
<section>
<ul id="edit" contenteditable="true">
<li>List item one</li>
</ul>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Javascript:

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $(function($) {
        var edit = document.getElementById('edit');
        $(edit).blur(function(){
            localStorage.setItem('todoData', this.innerHTML);
            });

        if(localStorage.getItem('todoData')){
            edit.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('todoData');
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Does HTML5 need `<script>` tags around your JS?

Comment: I believe so. I want that code to be external, though. In the file html5.js. But yes, if you were to include it in the html document, it would still require <script> tags, but it does not require you to declare 'type="text/javascript"'

Comment: oh...gotcha. I fixed the formatting for you to make that a bit clearer.

Comment: Did you try adding jQuery directly? http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you want the list item to be editable? If so you are missing a (document).ready

Edit: Whoops, not reading properly. You want the editable list to show any changes if user leaves and returns to page? Well it's working for me locally using both methods.

Maybe stupid question but are you linking to your external .js file properly? I noticed that the src="/html5.js" and not "html5.js" and when I do the former it doesn't work for me...

Comment: Yes, I figured it out yesterday, but forgot to visit back here! That is exactly the problem! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted